# Lost Huawei P30 Pro and data protection

Tags: security, huawei, lost-phone

I recently lost my Huawei P30 Pro smartphone and I'm concerned because the phone contained personal data.

I don't want anyone to get access to that data.

The phone was protected by a 6 figure password (unlock password).

Is that enough to make sure that my data is 100% protected and that if someone finds the phone, they would have to reset the phone and clear all the data on it before being able to use it? Is it also impossible to access the phone's data by plugging it to a PC with a USB cable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can not be 100% protected.  There is a tiny, finite chance that someone can guess your PIN/password.  The best thing in the future is to install some sort of Phone finder that can remotely wipe the data.

Comment: Ok, so you mean the only way someone can access my data is by guessing the code, there is no other way, right?

Comment: @Platus As long as the bootloader is locked and the device is encrypted, that is correct... The user data isn't decrypted until the initial PIN is entered on power-up. That said, if you had unlocked the bootloader, rooted it, or the device wasn't encrypted (unlikely if stock), then all bets are off and anyone with simple Android knowledge and a PC may be able to access the user date.